# add-migration command fails on ApplicationDbContex

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity-3

**App**: Asp.NET Core 1.1.1, EF Core

**Platform**: Visual Studio 2017 5.3.3

**Authentication Mode**: Individual User Accounts

Following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db) from ASP.NET official team, the following command runs successfully:

```
PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration -context BloggingContext
```

As we know `VS2017` by default creates `ApplicationDbContext` under MyProject\Data folder for creating user tables (`ASPNETUsers, ASPNETRoles etc...`) for authentication. But for that when I run the following command it first gives me `Error-1` below. And when I follow the instructions in first error message, I get `Error-2` below. **Question**: How do I make the following command work **without** using `IDbContextFactory`?

```
PM> Add-Migration MyFirstAuthenMigration -context ApplicationDbContext
```

**Error 1**

> No parameterless constructor was found on 'ApplicationDbContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'ApplicationDbContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory' in the same assembly as 'ApplicationDbContext'.

After I add a parameterless constructor in `ApplicationDbContext.cs` (shown below) I get the second error shown below:

**Error 2**

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    //NOTE: I added following constructor after Error 1 shown above
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your BloggingContext class inherit from DbContext?
Your ApplicationDbContext class inherits from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>.

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath 1. Yes (same as shown in the above [linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db) tutorial). And the first PM command works fine. 2. Yes (as shown in the above ApplicationDbContext.cs class)

Comment: Do you have all the necessary entity framework nugget packages installed? Maybe you should inherit from DbContext instead? There's a code line in the tutorial you linked that calls the AddDbContext() method (the method mentioned in your error 2). You might need to call that method. Also do you have DbSet<> properties set up?

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath In `startup.cs` I had replaced `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));` with `var connection = @"Server=MyMachine\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ForgotPswd;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));` Is that correct?

Comment: Try using ApplicationDbContext instead of BloggingContext since ApplicationDbContext is the class you are trying to fix.  Or you could have made sure the "DefaultConnection" connection string is set up correctly.

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath But BloggingContext part in the above comment is needed as instructed in the `Register your context with dependency injection` section of the [linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db) tutorial. I think the confusion is that the linked tutorial is not using `Authentication mode` while I'm although using the tutorial but with an extra step that is with `Authentication mode`. And for Blogs and Posts tables to be in play I do need BloggingContext registered with `Dependency Injection`.

Comment: Are you registering both context classes with dependency injection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153634/discussion-between-nam-and-anthony-mcgrath).

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it to work.
Because EF needs to know which connectionstring should be used. You can either put the connectionstring into your OnModelCreating method.
Which is bad when you have more than one DB (dev, test and production for example). 
Or you implement IDbContextFactory which will be loaded by EF through reflection.

So implementing IDbContextFactory is the better option. Simply create it where you have your ApplicationDbContext.
Sample implementation.

```
public class DomainContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<DomainContext>
{
    public string BasePath { get; protected set; }

    public DomainContext Create()
    {
        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        var basePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
        return Create(basePath, environmentName);
    }

    public DomainContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
        => Create(options.ContentRootPath, options.EnvironmentName);

    private DomainContext Create(string basePath, string environmentName)
    {
        BasePath = basePath;
        var configuration = Configuration(basePath, environmentName);
        var connectionString = ConnectionString(configuration.Build());
        return Create(connectionString);
    }

    private DomainContext Create(string connectionString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(connectionString)} is null or empty", nameof(connectionString));
        }
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DomainContext>();
        return Configure(connectionString, optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected virtual IConfigurationBuilder Configuration(string basePath, string environmentName)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(basePath)
            .AddJsonFile("constr.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"constr.{environmentName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        return builder;
    }

    protected virtual string ConnectionString(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        string connectionString = configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
        return connectionString;
    }

    protected virtual DomainContext Configure(string connectionString, DbContextOptionsBuilder<DomainContext> builder)
    {
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, opt => opt.UseRowNumberForPaging());
        DomainContext db = new DomainContext(builder.Options);
        return db;
    }

    DomainContext IDbContextFactory<DomainContext>.Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
        => Create(options.ContentRootPath, options.EnvironmentName);
}
```

It works with 3 configuration files (final, local and test)

- constr.dev-final.json
- constr.dev-local.json
- constr.dev-test.json

The usage looks like the following:

```
public override IServiceResult<IList<Rolle>> LoadAllData()
{
    using (var db = this.DomainContextFactory.Create())
    {
        Task<List<Rolle>> rollen = db.Roles
            .ToListAsync<Rolle>();
        return new ServiceResult<IList<Rolle>>(rollen.Result, rollen.Result.Count);

    }
}
```

And using "Add-Migration" inside MSVC works also.